# Java NIO selector for incoming connections and selector for incoming messages

Tags: java, sockets, nio

i'm trying to use NIO to build an efficient Socket TCP/IP server.

i have the main thread which accept connection and then add it to another thread which supposed to wait for messages from client and then read it.

when i'm using only one thread and one selector for all the operations it works great, but when i'm trying to make it works with 2 threads and 2 selectors the incoming connection accept is working but the reading is not, i think it because my selector is blocking the thread and therefor he's not aware that I've registered a new SocketChannel.

this is my Main thread:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {
      System.out.println("Who's Around Server Started!");
      Selector connectionsSelector = null;
      ServerSocketChannel server = null;
      String host = "localhost";
      int port = 80;    
      LiveConnectionsManager liveConnectionsManager =
         new LiveConnectionsManager();
      liveConnectionsManager.start();
      connectionsSelector = Selector.open();
      server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
      server.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(host,port));
      server.configureBlocking(false);
      server.register(connectionsSelector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
      while (true) {
         connectionsSelector.select();
         Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator =
            connectionsSelector.selectedKeys().iterator();
         while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            SelectionKey incomingConnection = iterator.next();
            iterator.remove();
            if( incomingConnection.isConnectable()) {
               ((SocketChannel)incomingConnection.channel()).finishConnect();
            }
            if( incomingConnection.isAcceptable()){
               acceptConnection(server.accept(), liveConnectionsManager);
            }
         }
      }
   } catch (Throwable e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Server failure: " + e.getMessage());
   } 
}

private static void acceptConnection(
   SocketChannel acceptedConnection,
   LiveConnectionsManager liveConnectionsManager ) throws IOException
{
   acceptedConnection.configureBlocking(false);
   acceptedConnection.socket().setTcpNoDelay(true);
   System.out.println(
      "New connection from: " + acceptedConnection.socket().getInetAddress());
   liveConnectionsManager.addLiveConnection(acceptedConnection);
}
```

and this is my LiveConnectionsManager:

```
private Selector messagesSelector;

public LiveConnectionsManager(){
   try {
      messagesSelector = Selector.open();           
   } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Couldn't run LiveConnectionsManager");
   }
}


@Override
public void run() {
   try {
      System.out.println("LiveConnectionManager Started!");
      while(true) {             
         messagesSelector.select();
         Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = messagesSelector.keys().iterator();
         while (iterator.hasNext()){
            SelectionKey newData = iterator.next();
            iterator.remove();
            if( newData.isReadable()){
               readIncomingData(((SocketChannel)newData.channel()));
            }
         }
      }
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}

public void addLiveConnection( SocketChannel socketChannel )
   throws ClosedChannelException
{
   socketChannel.register(messagesSelector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);      
}
```

Comment: Instead of building your own NIO Server why don't you take a look at [Netty](https://netty.io/).

Comment: Do it all in one thread. There is no great advantage to your design, and it is very difficult to multi-thread NIO.